Мини приложение закрывается после tg.sendData()
Я отправляю данные боту следующим образом:
let tg = window.Telegram.WebApp;
tg.sendData(JSON.stringify(data));
Данные бот получает и успешно может обработать. Но проблема в том что мини приложение закрывается после того как бот получит данные. А нужно чтобы не закрывалось.
Открываю мини-приложение через ReplyKeyboard()

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример
